# What is CSS, Themes and Skin in ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, themes, skin

I am a beginner in ASP.Net. I want to know what is CSS, Themes and Skin in ASP.Net? and How to create and use these things in ASP.Net? Please explain with simple example. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSS stands for cascading style sheets and is independent of ASP.NET. CSS is used to apply layout and visual style to elements on a page, for instance to make headings red:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6
{
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

Learn more about CSS here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp

Themes and Skins are a way in ASP.NET to decouple the visual appearance of your server controls from the markup, and allow you to swap out the visual appearance at run time by changing the theme.  From the MSDN page:

> A theme is a collection of property
>   settings that allow you to define the
>   look of pages and controls, and then
>   apply the look consistently across
>   pages in a Web application, across an
>   entire Web application, or across all
>   Web applications on a server.

Read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh.aspx